# AlarmManager Alarms every 30 min instead of everyday

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have a simple app with one activity that should show a notification everyday at a specific time.
these are my classes :

onAlarmReceiver

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context, AppService.class));
    }
}
```

onBootReceiver

```
public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        AlarmController alarm = new AlarmController(context);
        alarm.StartAlarm();
    }
}
```

AppService to make notification

```
public class AppService extends Service {
    private static String TAG = "AppService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "start job");
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            // There are no active networks.
        } else{
            Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =   new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) // notification icon
            .setContentTitle("اtitle") // title for notification
            .setContentText("content") // message for notification
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(uri); // clear notification after click

        Intent intentt = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intentt,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
    //
    Log.i(TAG, "stop job");
    return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

AlarmController class that includes my alarmmanager

```
public class AlarmController {

    private Context m_Context;
    private AlarmManager mgr;
    private PendingIntent pi;

    public AlarmController(Context context) {
        m_Context = context;
    }

    public void StartAlarm() {

        mgr = (AlarmManager)m_Context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent i = new Intent(m_Context, OnAlarmReceiver.class);

        pi=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(m_Context,0 ,i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
        Log.i("AlarmController", "StartAlarm");
        mgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
    }    
}
```

and I wrote this in onCreate method of MainActivity

```
AlarmController alarm = new AlarmController(this);
        alarm.StartAlarm();
```

even put this code in a method to just run on the first time that app will install.
but still it'll show notifications almost every 30 min instead of everyday.

What should I do? What's wrong in my codes?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to get an alarm every 24 hours since the app was launched, or you want to get it at the same time of day - 17:40 daily?

Comment: at the same time - 17:40!

Answer (score 0):

your class AlarmController must extend BroadcastReceiver

Comment: my onAlarmReceiver class extends BroadcastReceiver and I called Alarmmanager there. But now i changed     return START_STICKY;
 to         return START_NOT_STICKY; in my service and didn't get any notif for more than 1 hour! hope don't get until next day!